# Composite function $h(g(x))$ // Derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives

"Given the function $f(x) = sin(x^3-5x^2+4)$, find $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, knowing that $f(x) = h(g(x))$".

I only know how to do this kind of exercise when 2 of the 3 functions are given. In this case, only 1 is given. I suspect that is has something to do with derivates, because this question is from a derivative exercises list.

I found that $f'(x) = \cos(x^3+5x^2+4)\cdot(3x^2-10x)$.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Your expression for $f'(x)$ is correct, except for the typo $\color{red}+5x^2$. The problem was just asking you to decompose $f(x)$ into $h(g(x))$. There are many ways to do this, but here there is a particularly easy way, which you have found and used to do the chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decomposing a function into multiple nested functions can often be done in several ways.  You start at the $x$ and add as many operations as you want, then the rest of the operations become the outer function.  For example: $$f(x) = \sin^3(x^2 + 4)$$ can be divided up as $f(x) = g(h(x))$ where

$h(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = \sin^3(x+4)$ or

$h(x) = x^2 + 4$ and $g(x) = \sin^3(x)$ or

$h(x) = \sin(x^2+4)$ and $g(x) = x^3$.

If you needed it broken up further, $f(x) = g(h(j(x)))$, you could write

$j(x) = x^2+4$, $h(x) = \sin x$, and $g(x) = x^3$.  There are more ways to break it up; you might want to find them for practice.

Comment: Thank you so much, @RobertTheTutor!!!